# Age-distribution of a phase-type model

Tags: probability, markov-chains

My problem is as follows. I have a reaction system
$$X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow X_3 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow X_N \rightarrow X_1$$
where each transition happens at an exponential rate with parameter $\lambda$. Obviously, it is straightforward to find the steady state distributions of particles in $X_1,X_2,...$. Further, the time it takes a particle to transit from $X_1$ back to $X_1$ is clearly $\tau \sim Erlang(\lambda, N)$. If we say, however, that a particle begins with age $0$ in stage $X_1$, and its age resets to $0$ every time it returns to stage $X_1$ - at steady state, what is the distribution of particle ages?

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Obviously I could use a Monte-Carlo method to figure this out (and I have done), but I was wondering if there's a more analytic approach I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the steady state distribution, a random sample of the age of particles would follow a uniform distribution on the lifespan of each particle. Let $t$ denote the lifespan of particles, given by the Erlang distribution with $(\lambda,N)$ parameters and let $a$ be their age. Then the distribution of $a$ given $t$ should be Uniform on $[0,t]$. In other words it is a compound probability distribution.
$$ p(a) = \int p(a|t)p(t)\,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[0,t]}(a) \frac{\lambda^Nt^{N-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(N-1)!} \, dt$$
Here $\mathbb I_{[a,b]}$ denotes the indicator function on $[a,b]$. Note that $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[0,t]}(a)$ can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[a,\infty)}(t)$, so the bounds of integration only need to consider $[a,\infty)$.
$$ p(a) = \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \frac{\lambda^Nt^{N-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(N-1)!} \,dt $$
$$ = \frac{\lambda}{N-2}\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{N-1}t^{N-2}e^{-\lambda t}}{(N-2)!} \,dt $$
The integrand is now the density function of $Y\sim $ Erlang $(\lambda,N-1)$. 
$$ p(a) = \frac{\lambda}{N-2} \cdot P(Y\geq a) $$
$$ = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda a}}{N-2}\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}\frac{(\lambda a)^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: Are you sure about the "Note that $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[0,t]}(a)$ can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[a,\infty)}(t)$," part? In the first case $\frac{1}{t}$ goes from infinity to $\frac{1}{a}$ and in the second case from $\frac{1}{a}$ to 0?
In the step before you define Y, you need to take out one $\lambda$ to obtain the correct density.

Comment: @user585522 I just edited in your second remark about the factor of $\lambda$. On the first remark, we have $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[0,t]}(a)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}&\text{if }a\leq t\\ 0&\text{if }a>t\end{cases}$ and $\frac{1}{t}\mathbb I_{[a,\infty)}(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}&\text{if }t\geq a\\ 0&\text{if }t<a\end{cases}$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Do you perchance know how this derivation changes if one instead considers a system of the form $X_1 \rightarrow X_N \rightarrow kX_1$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: @J.Young I'm not sure what is meant by "$kX_1$" in this instance, can you explain?

Comment: @M.Nestor When a particle transitions back to $X_1$, it also creates $k-1$ new particles in stage $X_1$, both with age $0$ also.

Comment: @J.Young My intuition is that would not be solvable analytically. In that steady state, the number of particles is growing exponential with rate $k\lambda/N$. If we take a random sample, then a significant proportion will be newly-created particles (unlike in my answer, where the number of particles is constant). For newly-created particles, the distribution of ages seems very difficult to calculate, probably Monte-Carlo methods are preferred here.